# Найти случайное между определенными координатами

Tags: php

Есть 2 числа, которые представляют собой координаты карты. Задача найти случайное между ними. Не целое

```
$maxLat=-40.210409
$minLat=-41.457200
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно, например, вызывать [`lcg_value`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.lcg-value.php), которая возвращает число от 0.0 до 1.0.

```
function randomBetween($a, $b)
{
    return ($b - $a) * lcg_value() + $a;
}
```

Функция должна корректно работать и в случае `$a > $b`, и в случае `$b > $a`.

Answer (score 1):

Решение по вычислению случайного числа с плавающей точкой с [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mt-getrandmax.php):

```
function randomFloat($min = 0, $max = 1) {
    return $min + mt_rand() / mt_getrandmax() * ($max - $min);
}

$maxLat=-40.210409;
$minLat=-41.457200;
var_dump(randomFloat($minLat, $maxLat));
//float(-40.691939756979)
```

[Тест](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c29ae9186603d3a294d79ad68d3c56bab2f9f14)

[Аналогичный вопрос и ответы по поиску случайного числа с плавающей точкой на en.so](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14141212/5398808)